# Expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token

Tags: c++, oop, object, compilation, set

I receive this error that makes it difficult for me to continue coding, because I tried and tried to solve it and was unable to understand what the error means (I looked at similar questions in Stackoverflow).

I do not understand why, if I declare a set of Node objects as a type of data, I get these errors, code:

```
point p(p.get_x(),p.get_y());


Node a(p,0); 

set<Node&> visited_nodes;
```

The error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
         set<Node&> visited_nodes;
                 ^
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
         set<Node&> visited_nodes;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store references at containers. You should store pointers or the objects.

EDIT:
After chat session, we discovered the cause.
He was having a name conflict due to `using namespace std;`.

So I proposed:

```
std::set<Node> visited_nodes;
```

And the error dissapeared.

Comment: While true, the question is about a syntax error.

Comment: The error is related. As std::set is a templated class, I think the most clearer way to resolve his problem is to advice him that he cannot store references. More details can be confusing.

Comment: I don't see how the error is related at all. It's perfectly legal syntax to pass a reference as a template argument and the compiler is getting hung up on parsing. The only reason this is a problem is due to specific requirements on `std::set` (and other standard containers) about which types they support.

Comment: @LuisGP When i change it to that : set<Node> visited_nodes; , i get this error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

Comment: @AER then probably @aschepler is right. Did you included `set` or `using std::set`?

Comment: @LuisGP Yes, i include set library

Comment: @AER and `using std::set`?

Comment: @LuisGP I declared above the code using namespace std;

Comment: Then you are missing something. Is `Node` declared and in scope? Review your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verificable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as @chris asked for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183463/discussion-between-aer-and-luisgp).